# convert string to datetime format and date only in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert the string to datetime. I have following string:

```
08/19/2012 04:33:37 PM
```

I want to convert above string to following format date:

```
MM-dd-yyyy
```

and

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

I have been trying to convert using different technique and using following:

```
DateTime firstdate = DateTime.Parse(startdatestring);
```

It shows following error

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

I have search for it and couldn't get exact solution and also try using different format for datetime. Please how can I convert above string to above date format

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to parse the string first - you have missed out the AM/PM designator. Take a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN:

```
DateTime firstdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdatestring, 
                                         "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can format to a string:

```
var firstDateString = firstdate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Which you may also want to do with `InvariantCulture`:

```
var firstDateString = firstdate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: string is come from datepicker. When I select less than 12 for day it works fine otherwise show error like `The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.` that means day is taken as month. Where i have to change in code

Comment: @CodeManiac - If you are using a `DatePicker`, just use the `DateTime` it exposes directly - why are you going through a string representation at all?

Answer (score 5):

In **.NET 6** you can use the [DateOnly struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0)

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("08/19/2012 04:33:37 PM");

var dateOnly = DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime);
var dateOnlyString = dateOnly.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

or

```
var dateOnlyString = DateOnly.Parse("08/19/2012").ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Output: `08-19-2012`